# Analysing Data in R and I want to export a Graph into powerpoint

Tags: r, graph, powerpoint

I am currently analysing Data in R and I created a Graph that I would like to export into a Powerpoint document. There, I would like to be able to make changes. I found the RDCOMClient package as a possible solution but the newer R versions don't seem to support this anymore

I tried to install the RDCOMClient package but it is not supported by my R version 3.6.1 and

```
p = ggplot(aes(x=Precuneus_hit_core_centered,y=Predicted,colour=Shame_vs_NoShame),data=X)
p + geom_smooth(method="lm",se=TRUE,size=2, aes(fill=Shame_vs_NoShame)) +
  labs(y="FR",x="Precuneus",colour="Shame_vs_NoShame",fill="Shame_vs_NoShame")+
  opts + guides(color=guide_legend(keywidth = 2, keyheight = 2))
ggsave('Shame_vs_NoShamexPrecuneus_hit_core_centered3.pptx',width=8)
```

I would like to export the graph that I have created based on that code into powerpoint.

I got this information:

package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)

I also tried it for the R version 3.6.1

Comment: Have you tried the [officer package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/index.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rstudio, have you tried to work with Rmarkdown ? You can output your result directly as a Powerpoint presentation.

````
---
title: "My Powerpoint presentation"
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


## My Graph

```{r, echo= FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = qsec))+
  geom_density()
```
````

More information [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/powerpoint-presentation.html).